# copy constuctor of templated class does not always work for newer gcc

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, gcc, copy-constructor

I am maintaining some legacy C++ code, which worked fine so far. Recently I switched from Ubuntu 16.04 (gcc 5.4) to Ubuntu 18.04 (gcc 7.3) and the code did not compile anymore (With clang 6.0 it did however). I am pretty sure it is c++ version thing. I have made changes to the code and it compiles now, but I would like to have some explanation of what is going on exactly.

The culprit is the copy constructor of the following fast hash map class

```
template< typename Key, typename Val, size_t (*hashf)(Key const &), typename KeyCompare = std::equal_to<Key> >
class fhash_map
{
public:
  fhash_map(fhash_map const & copy);
}
```

Now there is some other class, let's call it *UseFull*, which has various *fhash_map* members (I call this Variant A)

```
template<typename Stype>
class UseFull<Stype>: public UseFullParent< Scalar<Stype> >
{
private:
  fhash_map<A, B, C> _this_works;
  fhash_map<A, Spline*, C> _this_does_not_work;
  fhash_map<A, std::vector<Spline*>, C> _neither_does_this;
public:
  UseFull(UseFull const & copy)
  : UseFullParent(copy)
  {
    _this_works(copy._this_works);
    _this_does_not_work(copy._this_does_not_work);
    _neither_does_this(copy._neither_does_this);
  }
}
```

With gcc 7.3 this fails to compile with the messages

```
error: no match for call to ‘(fhash_map<A, Spline*, C>) (fhash_map<A, Spline*, C>&)’
error: no match for call to ‘(fhash_map<A, std::vector<Spline*>, C>) (fhash_map<A, std::vector<Spline*>, C>&)’
```

Note that the compiler only complains about the to latter members (as indicated by their names), not about the first member (*_this_works*).

If I now change the copy constructor (Variant B) of the *UseFull* class to read

```
  UseFull(UseFull const & copy)
  : UseFullParent(copy)
  ,_this_works(copy._this_works)
  ,_this_does_not_work(copy._this_does_not_work)
  ,_neither_does_this(copy._neither_does_this)
  {
  }
```

It works fine.

My questions are:

1. why does Variant A work with an older gcc and not with a newer
2. what could be so special about some of the members? Is it the Spline class? What could be going on there (It seems pretty normal to me)
3. what exactly is the difference between Variant A and Variant B? (That makes the difference in this case)

Comment: VariantA doesn't look legal to me as fhash_map doesn't overload operator(), at least not in the code you've posted.

Comment: VariantB is not legal because of the semi-colons in the initialiser list. It's important to cut and paste real code in cases like this.

Comment: VariantA: fhash_map does not have an operator(). So you are saying in Variant A it calls the operator() instead of the copy constructor? Why does it then work for the *_this_works* member?
VariantB: oops my bad. I removed the semi-colons.
I wanted to have speaking variable names, and am furthermore not really allowed to post real code as it is under a non-free license.

Comment: `_this_works(copy._this_works);` looks like a call to operator(). I don't know how else to interpret it and I don't know how g++ is interpretting it. But it seems VariantB is the code you want.

Comment: Is UseFull a template class? Maybe the constructor was not generated at phase 2, but was ok for phase 1?

Comment: It is indeed. I changed it in my original description. Also the gcc error was wrong. It refers to fhash_map not to UseFull. Sorry for that